# How do I JSON.stringify( anObject ) without colons, backslashes, curly braces or quotes?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, express, stringify

`This is a simple sentence. I don't want anything <form><b>but</b></form> this.`

But after some client-side html manipulation and...

```
var newBody = JSON.stringify(req.body);
```

followed by an update to MongoDb,

```
var update = { '$set' :{ 'body' : newBody} }
```

I have this:

```
body: '{"This is a simple sentence. I don\'t want anything <form><b>but</b></form> this. ":""}'
```

And when I convert it back to html it has curley braces and quotes, which exacerbate with each update.  I looked [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify), and have tried escape back-slashes, but I can't figure it out.  Thank you.

```
{"{\"This is a simple sentence. I <form><b>don't</b></form> want this. \":\"\"}"}
```

Comment: Try `escape(JSON.stringify(req.body))`

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more on your setup and what you're trying to do?

Comment: It sounds like you're JSON'ifying JSON .. long and short of it is: don't.

Comment: Thanks, but than I get some craz%in%ess ;)

Comment: I'm trying to manipulate a string using html, and than update the html in mongodb.  When the user logs back in I want the updated html to have replaced the old html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe JSON.stringify is unncessary, assuming you passed post parameters `simpleSentance= 'I dont want anything <b>but</b> this'`

```
var newBody = req.body.simpleSentance
```

Comment: I thought the key was `body`?